# MooTools images list

Tags: javascript, mootools, slideshow

I have this HTML:

```
<div id='cont'>
    <img src='1.jpg' />
    <img src='2.jpg' />
    <img src='2.jpg' />
</div>

<a href='#'>Prev</a>
<a href='#'>Next</a>
```

with this CSS:

```
#cont{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    height: 90px;
    width: 120px;
}

#cont img {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

clicking *Next* and *Prev* I need to show images. What is the easiest way to do this with MooTools?

Comment: And what have you tried? What went wrong? How about posting a [JS Fiddle demo of what you've currently got/tried](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 1):

oddly enough, just wrote a tutorial on how to do this in mootools on my blog yesterday.

http://fragged.org/tutorial-write-a-small-content-slider-class-in-mootools-and-extend-it_1321.html

the actual code is geared up to work with any kind of absolute elements so it can easily work for you. next and previous are images but you can replace them with anchors.

here are the two classes (the base and the extended one for the different effect):

```
this.contentSwapper = new Class({

    Implements: [Options, Events],

    options: {
        delay: 3000,
        selector: "div",
        controlLeft: "http://fragged.org/img/home/moveLeft.png",
        controlRight: "http://fragged.org/img/home/moveRight.png"
    },

    initialize: function(element, options) {
        this.element = document.id(element);
        if (!this.element)
            return;

        this.setOptions(options);

        this.elements = this.element.getChildren(this.options.selector);
        this.index = 0;
        this.attachControls();
        this.startRotation();
        this.attachEvents();
        this.fireEvent("ready");
    },

    attachControls: function() {
        this.controls = $$([
            new Element("img#moveLeft.contentControl[title=Previous][src={controlLeft}]".substitute(this.options)).inject(this.element, "top"),
            new Element("img#moveRight.contentControl[title=Next][src={controlRight}]".substitute(this.options)).inject(this.element, "top")
        ]);
    },


    attachEvents: function() {
        this.element.addEvents({
            mouseenter: this.stopRotation.bind(this),
            mouseleave: this.startRotation.bind(this),
            "click:relay(img.contentControl)": this.move.bind(this)
        });
    },

    move: function(e, el) {
        this[el.get("id")]();
    },

    moveLeft: function() {
        var next = (this.index == 0) ? this.elements.length-1 : this.index-1;
        this.swapFrames(next);
        this.fireEvent("left");
    },

    moveRight: function() {
        var next = (this.index < this.elements.length-1) ? this.index+1 : 0;
        this.swapFrames(next);
        this.fireEvent("right");
    },

    swapFrames: function(next) {
        // internal to do the swaps
        var curEl = this.elements[this.index];
        curEl.get("tween").removeEvents();
        curEl.set({
            "tween": {
                link: "cancel",
                onComplete: function() {
                    this.element.addClass("hide");
                }
            },
            styles: {
                opacity: 1
            }
        }).fade(0);

        this.index = next;

        var newEl = this.elements[this.index];
        newEl.get("tween").removeEvents();
        newEl.setStyle("opacity", 0).removeClass("hide").fade(1);
    }.protect(),

    stopRotation: function() {
        clearInterval(this.timer);
        this.controls.fade(1);
        this.fireEvent("stop");
    },

    startRotation: function() {
        clearInterval(this.timer);
        this.controls.fade(.5);
        this.timer = this.moveRight.periodical(this.options.delay, this);
        this.fireEvent("start");
    }
});


contentSwapper.Fancy = new Class({

    Extends: contentSwapper,

    initialize: function(element, options) {
        this.parent(element, options);
    },

    swapFrames: function(next) {
        var curEl = this.elements[this.index];
        curEl.get("morph").removeEvents();
        curEl.set({
            styles: {
                zIndex: 1000,
                opacity: 1
            },
            "morph": {
                link: "cancel",
                duration: 1000,
                onComplete: function() {
                    this.element.addClass("hide");
                }
            }
        }).morph({
            opacity: 0
        });

        this.index = next;

        var newEl = this.elements[this.index];
        newEl.get("morph").removeEvents();
        newEl.removeClass("hide").setStyles({
            zIndex: 1001,
            marginTop: -280,
            opacity: 0
        }).morph({
            marginTop: 0,
            opacity: 1
        });
    }

});

new contentSwapper.Fancy(document.id("rotator"));
```

the html:

```
<section class="rotator" id="rotator">
    <div class="pane" style="background-image:url(http://fragged.org/img/home/hunting-home.jpg)">
        <div class="info">
            <h2>Hunting CS style</h2>
            Built for your `camping` pleasure. nOOb
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pane hide" style="background-image:url(http://fragged.org/img/home/fishing-home.jpg)">
        <div class="info">
            <h2>Fishing? Really? </h2>
            Fishing is for mongs. <a href="#">Clcik here</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pane hide" style="background-image:url(http://fragged.org/img/home/tourism-home.jpg)">
       <div class="info rambling">
           <h2>Rambling and walking</h2>
           Wish you were here? Can't blame you, it's lame.
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

etc etc. have fun